# Keep all future pages inside first PHP window

Tags: javascript, php

I have a webpage with an include statement inside a div tag.

```
<div id="rsvp">
    include('rsvp');
</div>
```

The second file displays correctly. It has a post to update a database with variables entered on the second page.

```
<div id="rsvp">
    <? include('rsvp.php'); ?>
</div>
```

This third page, identified in the post action, executes exactly as expected. The problem is that the third page does not display inside the div tag of the first file. Instead of that it replaces the first page display in favor of itself. How can I use an include statement in a primary file and have the posting process of the included file remain inside the div tag of the original page?

I hope I have explained the enough to get some feedback.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: try it `<?php include('rsvp.php'); ?>`

Comment: Did you intend the missing `<?php ?>` tag in your first example?

Comment: sorry, the first example should have the <?php include('rsvp.php'); ?> with it.  The second example should have been <post action="rsvp2.php">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring out that turning off the refresh after post in the second file allowed the display to stay within the division of the first page.  Wow  I put onSubmit="return false" inside the form command to stop the refresh.